# Why do I get the wrong value when I specify 'width' in 'tr'?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I've assigned '25px' to 'tr' in this photo, but 29 on the actual page.

I found out that 'border' goes right and left in css, and 2px is added.

I am wondering why 2px is applied when it becomes '27px' even if it does so.

The code below shows the code shown in the picture.

```css
.div_result {
    overflow-y: hidden;
 width: 766px;
 height: 250px;
 overflow-x: auto;
 border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
}

table.scroll {
 width: 150%;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

table.scroll tbody,
table.scroll thead {
 display: block;
}

thead tr th {
 height: 30px;

}

table.scroll tbody {
 height: 100px;
 overflow-y: auto;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

tbody td,
thead th {
 border: 1px solid black;
}

tbody td:last-child,
thead th:last-child {}

thead tr {
 display: inline-table;
 width: 100%;
}

th {
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div_result  " style="position:relative;">
 <table id="" class="scroll">
  <thead class="sorted_head">
   <tr>
    <th id="" class="result_title " width="25">
     <span class="some-handle">a</span>
    </th>
    <th id="" class="result_title " width="120">
     <span class="some-handle">a</span>
    </th>
    <th id="" class="result_title " width="250">
     <span class="some-handle">a</span>
    </th>
    <th class="result_title ">
     <span class="some-handle">a</span>
    </th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="sort_body">
   <tr>
    <td style="padding: 0;width: 25px;">asd</td>
    <td style="width: 120px;">asd</td>
    <td style="width: 250px;">asd</td>
    <td style="width: 738px;">asd</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It shows 27px for me, what browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

CSS table will auto-space it's columns based on *first* row. Also you need `table {table-layout: fixed}` for it to work:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log($('table td:first').outerWidth());
})
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: blue;
}

td:first-child {
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```